# Size of SLES iso is more than OpenSUSE. Why?

Tags: opensuse, suse, sles

I can't wrap my head around the fact that the size of SLES (SUSE Linux enterprise server) 15 SP2 is more than the size of OpenSuse Leap.

[Here](https://get.opensuse.org/leap/#) the size for `Intel or AMD 64-bit desktops, laptops, and servers (x86_64)` offline image is 4.4 GB, whereas the size for `SLE-15-SP2-Full-x86_64-GM-Media1.iso` is mentioned as 10619977728( i am assuming this is in bytes, so in GB this would be around 10.6 GB) according to [this](https://www.suse.com/download/sles/) site

Also, according to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux#SUSE_Linux_Enterprise) link

> SUSE Linux Enterprise has fewer packages than the openSUSE
> distribution. Most of the differences are desktop applications that
> are more suited to consumers than to business.

So, how is it that SLES size is more than OpenSUSE?
I don't have access to the internet during installation, so I can't use the online iso image. Is there any other option?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see https://www.suse.com/download/sled/ ..... Huge sizes indicates all packages are included. Which is convenient for a server with no Internet connection. .......  OpenSuse Leap is used with the Net , and packages can be installed with zypper.

Comment: @KnudLarse  But I need to reduce the size of the ISO because I definitely won't be using all the packages. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I will look into this. thanks a mil.  :)

Comment: (Corretion:) SLE 15 netinstall → "14.2 Creating a Minimal Boot Image" https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP2/html/SLES-all/cha-deployment-prep-mksusecd.html ....... I have never used a Suse netintall, but for CentOS and Debian it's a few hundred MB, say 300 .. 800.